# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib==0.1.59

Tags: python, installation, error-handling, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install package "genomicsurveillance" into the Jupyter notebook but it appears error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib==0.1.59 (from numpyro) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib==0.1.59
```

Thus, I tried to install jaxlib by:

```
pip install jaxlib==0.1.59 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html
```

However, it still appears the same error for jaxlib:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib==0.1.59 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib==0.1.59
```

How can I fix this error for the installation of jaxlib and then the package "genomicsurveillance"?
Thank you very much.

p/s: I am using Windows